# Counting the number of records of an angularfire2.5 Observable list and drop it in a Colspan

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-table, angularfire2

I'm having some problems trying to drop the number of records (members) of an observable list with angularfire2.5 RTDB, in a td colspan.

I manage calculate the number with the following code

```
{{ (members | async)?.length }}
```

But I don't know how to drop the number in a td colspan :

```
<td colspan="{{ (members | async)?.length }}">
```

Do I have to get the number from the controller and if so how can I do this.

I'm getting my list with the following code:

```
    this.members = db.list('members').snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
  return arr.map(snap => Object.assign(snap.payload.val(), { key: snap.key }) )
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<td [colSpan]="(members | async)?.length">
```

Comment: thanks Hareesh for your answer I'm getting the following error with your solution : "Can't bind to 'colspan' since it isn't a known property of 'td'"

Comment: S in colSpan is capital.